# Updated magento 1.9.0 to 1.9.2 then order emails are going continuously interval one second

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Updated magento to latest version 1.9.2.0 and setup a cronjob to send email then  order emails are going continuously.

I am using IWD onepage checkout and authorize.net for payment option.

everything is working except order emails are going continuously.

My inbox is full. then I have removed cronjob.

But I want to send order email.

I have checked exception log file it says

```
exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. ' in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:137
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail->_sendMail()
#1 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#2 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php(236): Zend_Mail->send()
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue->send(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule))
#4 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(326): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#6 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1357): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1336): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#8 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#9 /var/www/html/cron.php(75): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#10 {main}
```

Comment: can you mention in your question ,how did you setup cron.

Comment: */5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cron.php

Comment: If I enabled payment option cod and checked with COD its working properly

Comment: try to disable  IWD onepage checkout and place order using Magento default checkout and then see what happens?